# Complement of open unit disk homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 \geq 1\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?
I suppose that they are not, because they have different fundamental groups.

Comment: They are not homeomorphic and the reason you cited is a good one to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, for precisely the reason you stated.

Comment: And another reason is that only one of them has a transitive homeomorphism group.